# I am trying to put a name (see through Text- stencil) on a Flat piece of TPU

Tags: mesh, objects, interface, export

I am trying to put a name (see through Text- stencil) on a Flat piece of TPU, Sounds simple, but I'm having a hard time. I am New to this.

In Blender I just add a Plane, give it some thickness, then I put text in it, but I want to be able to see through the letters, as if they are cut out.

I also tried that with the knife in Blender. I am to new to this not enough experience.

Comment: Search for [Boolean](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are trying to do. [image]

If that is so,then make 2 objects. One rectangle with the thickness you want the piece of TPU to be and one text object.

The shortcut to add Text is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  > *Text*.

Make the text thickness you want from *Properties > Object Data Properties (green letter icon) > Geometry > Extrude/Offset*

Then move the text to overlap each other having a thicker text than the rectangle's thickness.

Make the Text a Mesh by selecting the text and from the top left of the viewport, *Object > Convert > Mesh*.

Have in mind that boolean modifier won't work if the text isn't a mesh. Choose the rectangle, make a boolean modifier from *Properties > Modifier Properties* and pick *Boolean*. Select the Text as the object and apply the modifier by hitting <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
If you apply and move the text object you can see the see-through text.